# Creating drop-down menu in Google Script custom dialogue, with options from data in a Google Sheet

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I am looking to create a drop down menu in a custom dialogue when you run a script. I have been successful in doing so, and also able to create a loop in a  element that creates a drop down list from a static array [i.e. an array of months and create a drop down menu]. However, I have been unsuccessful in being able to bull data from a google sheet, and using that data to create the drop-down menu.

Example code that works for creating drop-down menu from array:

```html
<form>
<select name="Month-test" id="month-selector-test" autofocus="autofocus" autocorrect="off" autocomplete="off">
  <option value="" selected="selected" id="todays-month"></option>
   <script> 
   // select this element
  var currentDayList = document.getElementById('month-selector-test');
  // array of all months
  var allMonthsAbv = ["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"];
  // for every element in the array, add an option
  for (var i=0; i<allMonthsAbv.length; i++) {
    currentDayList.innerHTML += '<option value=' + allMonthsAbv[i] + '>' + allMonthsAbv[i] + '</option>';
  }    
  </script>
</select>
</form>
```

Example code that does not work for creating drop down menu from data in sheet:

```html
<form>
<select name="Month" id="month-selector" autofocus="autofocus" autocorrect="off" autocomplete="off">
  <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
    <script>
    var monthList = document.getElementById('month-selector');
    
    var allData = SpreadsheetApp.openById('###ID###').getSheetByName('###NAME###').getDataRange().getValues();
    var list = [];
    for (var i=1;i<allData.length;i++) {
      var schoolName = allData[i][1];
      if (schoolName != "") {
      list.push(schoolName);
      }
    }
   for (var i = 0;i<list.length;i++) {
    monthList.innerHTML += '<option value=' + list[i] + '>' + list[i] + '</option>';
  }  
  </script>
</select>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have certainly written, and routinely use, code that does what you want. So I can say, for certain, that it can be done.

I should add the note that it is very very useful to do this.  The spreadsheet, is something that non-coders can update happily and then we generate code from that.

The thing that puzzles me about the code you have offered is your use of SpreadsheetApp   in HTML.

I have only ever done that in GAS code.  You may know something that I don't or that maybe will be the beginning of answering your question.

I make a lot of use of google.script.run Do you?

Answer (score 0):

You are using pop incorrectly. Change list.pop to list.push

```
  var monthList = document.getElementById('month-selector');

  var allData = SpreadsheetApp.openById('###ID###').getSheetByName('###NAME###').getDataRange().getValues();
  var list = [];
  for (var i=1;i<allData.length;i++) {
      var schoolName = allData[i][1];
      if (schoolName != "") {
        list.push(schoolName);
      }
    }
   for (var i = 0;i<list.length;i++) {
    monthList.innerHTML += '<option value=' + list[i] + '>' + list[i] + '</option>';
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, typo when I was entering the code, but still does not create the entries in the drop-down menu

Comment: @Kyle. I am unfamiliar with the HTML code, but the Google Apps Script is definitely reading from the spreadsheet. Can you log(allData) to make sure you are getting the right data in allData[i][1]?

Comment: Yes when I run the regular script it logs all of the data fine, however when used within a HTML element it fails to produce the data

Answer (score 0):

So the next question is - can you move easily, and routinely, between the foreground (HTML) and the background (GAS)

I ask this because it was the key for me

Comment: I have repeated this exercise just now (I have to confess that my confidence was based on the, conceptually similar, but nevertheless different example of radio checkboxes and it is **not** simple.
To the point where simply sharing my code would not be helpful.
Can I offer to step you into it?
I need to be frank. I am collecting reputation points so that my own question will be taken more seriously

Answer (score 0):

OK - I have done what I should have done before and tried running your code and have come up with a number of **quite distinct** (ie separate, but very definite) issues. I am left with one that I have yet to resolve but I thought I should keep you posted. I will try to address them all before putting in the working code.

- When does the code get triggered? This **must happen** in the HTML body onload event for the drop-down to be populated. The only way I know for code to be made to be triggered at that point in GAS is via a "successHandler" for a GAS call.
  Hence:

  The nullFunction() (GAS, ie backend) does nothing, it just causes addMonths() to be called when the body has loaded and then populate the drop-down.
- What attributes does the select tag support?
  You were using id and the associated getElementById() call but select does not support the id attribute, hence:

  You then have to get your head around the fact that getElementsByName() returns a node-list, so you need to add to the innerHtml of [0] in that list. Hence:
    var currentDayList = document.getElementsByName('month-selector-test')[0];
- Where should the  block be placed?
  There are two aspects to this. You had put it within the  block. However, if it is in there it will be handled by your code as part of the innerHtml, so it must not go there!
  If you put it in the  it will not yet have loaded when onload is fired so it must go at the end of

Here is the working code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
<body onload='google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(addMonths).nullFunction();'>
  x x x 
<select name="month-selector-test">
</select>
   <script> 
  var currentDayList = document.getElementsByName('month-selector-test')[0];
   function addMonth(monthAbv){
   text=currentDayList.innerHTML;
  var firstPart='\<option value=\"';
  var secondPart='\"\>';
  var thirdPart='\<\/option\>';
  text=text + firstPart+name  + secondPart  + monthAbv + thirdPart;
  currentDayList.innerHTML+=text;
  }
  function addMonths(){
  var allMonthsAbv = ["Jan","Feb"];
  //"Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"];
  // for every element in the array, add an option
  for (var i=0; i<allMonthsAbv.length; i++) {
   addMonth(allMonthsAbv[i]);
    }
  }
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```